# spring rabbit is it required to declare queue for send a message

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I need to send a message to a queue with name "myQueue" to the MQ server. Should I declare all required beans in spring, like Queue and etc for it. It seems to me useless because I only need to send to server, and receive if possible, I`m not going to listen the queue, is it possible just to throw it there and forget, without any explicit configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I need to send a message to a queue with name "myQueue" to the MQ server. 
Should I declare all required beans in spring, like Queue and etc for it.
```

No. With out declaring beans like connection factory, exchange and queue you can not publish messages to queue.

```
It seems to me useless because I only need to send to server, and receive if possible, 
I`m not going to listen the queue, is it possible just to throw it there and forget, without any explicit configuration?
```

Spring is not super natural, though you consume your message or not if you want to push your message to queue spring should know the connection and queue details.

You can refer [my blog post](http://www.prathapchowdary.com/page2/) for more details on spring-rabbit programming.